# Objective C - Only part of an if condition working

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have an `if` statement and the statement is only being run on the fist third of the condition (before the fist 'or' (`||`).

```
if (((day == 1) && (period == 1)) || ((day == 3) && (period == 3)) || ((day = 5) && (period == 1)))
{
    NSLog(@"Return Line 1");
}
```

The condition is only met when `day = 1` and `period = 1`. Could someone help me get the other arrangements working in the condition. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me know what condition you need

Comment: Show values of variables when it is not working..

Comment: You can debug this: break the condition into three BOOL variables that you can inspect with the debugger; use a breakpoint to see the BOOL results and the day/period values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (((day == 1) && (period == 1)) || ((day == 3) && (period == 3)) || ((day == 5) && (period == 1)))
{
    NSLog(@"Return Line 1");
}
```

In your code there is only one = instead of ==

The error in your code is **((day = 5) && (period == 1))**